# Parameters weibull distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, weibull-distribution

If anyone can help me with this question i would be very thankfull

An article in IEEE Transactions on Dielectrics and Electrical Insulation [“Statistical Analysis of the AC Breakdown Voltages of Ester Based Transformer Oils” (2008, Vol. 15(4))] used Weibull distributions to model the breakdown voltage of insulators. The breakdown voltage is the minimum voltage at which the insulator conducts. For 1 mm of natural ester, the 1% probability of breakdown voltage is approximately 26 kV, and the 7% probability is approximately 31.6 kV.

****Determine the parameters δ and β of the Weibull distribution.****

obs: i tried to solve the system $P(X=26)=F(26)=1-e^{-(26/\sigma)^\beta}=0.01$ and $P(X=31.6)=F(31.6)=1-e^{-(31.6/\sigma)^\beta}=0.07$ but i got absurd values.

Comment: is possible that i misunderstood some concept. Could you explain to me?

Comment: What do you call absurd? I find $\sigma \approx 40.9348$ and $\beta \approx 10.1351$.

Comment: But you did with de CFD like me ? because i found $\sigma$ imaginary and $\beta=9.98$. I would appreciate if you could explain how do you got this results or i get a really high values for $\sigma$, way higher than yours.

Comment: Yes, I used the CFD. For simplicity, write $(\frac{26}{\sigma})^\beta=c$ and $(\frac{31.6}{\sigma})^\beta=d$. Now we have to solve $e^{-c}=0.99$ and $e^{-d}=0.93$. This results in $c \approx 0.01$ and $d \approx 0.0725$, solving the resulting system for $\sigma$ and $\beta$ yields the results.

Comment: I would like to thank for the explanation. I did the same as you but i did something wrong. Probably i lost some step in calculation.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Actually, i did again those calculation now in maple and still the set os solutions was  40.95522465,33.33378346+23.79473275∗I,13.30603892+38.73344490∗I,−11.67400140+39.25618572∗I,−32.30916431+25.16839938∗I,−40.91937080+1.713335612∗I,−40.91937080−1.713335612∗I,−32.30916431−25.16839938∗I,−11.67400140−39.25618572∗I,13.30603892−38.73344490∗I,33.33378346−23.79473275∗I